# spring+hibernate+jetty Null pointer exception while entering entity manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting a null pointer exception as soon as entity manager of hibernate tries to create query.entity manager is not null(it is having a context) while i tried to debug.

Below is the exact exception i am getting

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.executeExactExceptionMapper(ExceptionHandler.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyNoResourceFoundView$1.handle(ResteasyNoResourceFoundView.java:43)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyNoResourceFoundView$1.handle(ResteasyNoResourceFoundView.java:38)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.handle(ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyNoResourceFoundView.render(ResteasyNoResourceFoundView.java:37)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is the **persistence-config.xml**.**This is imported in application context**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="aspu" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
            <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
            </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ASDB" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root@123" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="aspu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <class>main.java.com.as.entity.MobileAppEntity</class>
         <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
       </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
```

**DAO impl class**

```
package main.java.com.as.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import main.java.com.as.entity.MobileAppEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class ASDAOImpl implements ASDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="aspu")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean validateCapping(String loyaltyId, int capLimit) {
        String query = "select processId from MobileAppEntity;";
        String cappingCount = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().toString();
        if (Integer.parseInt(cappingCount) > capLimit)
            return false;
        return true;

    }
```

I am getting the above exception at `entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().toString();`

Comment: Maybe there is nothing to fill the resultList. If it is null, then null pointer exception is normal. Are you sure that it gives a list?

Comment: Yes..In the DB i inserted a process_Id to the table..so i wrote this query..

Comment: Did you first just try to get query.list() back, and after that check for null condition and then only process it. Also, you are telling the DB just give me processId's for all the rows, don't forget that.

Comment: Also, this way to do stuff defeats the purpose of using Hibernate as an ORM, which makes it easier to retrieve object/s, or list and then iterate through them.

Comment: only 1 row i inserted into the table with process_Id=1..so the given query should return 1..the exception is occuring at entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().toString();

Comment: Is the semicolon correct? I think you don't need it. Please remove the ";"  in your query string. And/or show us the entity

Comment: Thanks Si mo..u r great..its working now !!!

Comment: thx :-) I will post it as anwer :-). Please mark it as "answer" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon is incorrect. Remove it from the query string

Answer (score 0):

You used mysql as database but you define jpaVendorAdapter bean for HSQL DB

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
</bean>
```

Change to

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
</bean>
```

Add JpaVendorAdapter Provider so replace all code in persistance.xml by following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="aspu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <class>main.java.com.as.entity.MobileAppEntity</class>
         <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
       </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
```

Finally:
Modify method as below:

```
public boolean validateCapping(String loyaltyId, int capLimit) {
       /*
          Remove semicolon and get single result for one object from result set
          Check result value is null or not before parsing otherwise thows NPE
       */
        String query = "select m.processId from MobileAppEntity m";
        String cappingCount = entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();

        if (cappingCount != null && Integer.parseInt(cappingCount) > capLimit)
            return false;
        return true;

    }
```

Note: if you try to parse null value of `cappingCount` then Null Pointer Exception without checking  is not null before parsing `String` to `Integer`

Comment: Please send all stack trace of exception top to buttom

Comment: i think it is attached here..i copy pasted the whole exception trace from eclipse console

Comment: Thanks bhuwan..its problem with the sql query..added a semicolon